# Why don't I have the appraisal feature in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why is the appraisal feature missing on my account?

I have reinstalled the app twice but still no appraisal.

Answer (score 5):

There are two requirements to unlock the appraisal feature.

1. Choose a team - available at trainer level 5 by visiting a gym.
2. Must be at least trainer level 7.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use the appraisal feature if you are a part of a team. The menu option appears in the same context menu where you transfer pokemon.

Answer (score 2):

Even without the appraisal option you can get an estimate by typing in 1-4 and putting a star(*) into the search bar. It will show you all of the Pokémon that fall under each category separately. Also, I recommend downloading an IV application to give you a better look at your Pokémon, it will determine it based on CP and level. But as they said for the in game appraisal option you must choose a team by going to a gym and your character must be at least level 7.

Comment: With the recently improved appraisal features, I do wonder if the in-game one is better than an external IV application

Comment: @MBorg external IV has some nifty extra features, like calculating the max CP, candy/dust to reach that, PVP values (max CP <1500, <2500), etc. Also renaming is something I really appreciate from CalcyIV